# STS 3.4.0 with Websphere 8.5.5.0 don't deploy my application

Tags: eclipse, deployment, websphere, spring-tool-suite

I try to deploy my application on WebSphere from Eclipse.

Here some conditions:

- STS 3.4.0
- Websphere Plugin: IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Developer Tools for Kepler/Luna
- Websphere 8.5.5.0

After i installed the plugin i can add the Server and start/stop him, but when i try to add my application for deployment i get the feedback "There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server"

I have an ear project and a war project in my workspace which are deployable with JBoss without problems. Do i have to add something to my projects to make them deployable?

Is there any clue for this?

*** Update ***

Here you can see the project structure of my ear module.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround which is ok i think.

I created a "Enterprise Application Project" and added my war modules to it.
This was deployable with WebSphere.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add EAR projects via `right click on Server > Add and Remove...`. You should see dialog with projects that can be deployed to your server. If your EAR project is not visible there maybe it is not correctly recognized as EAR project. Check in Project properties > Project Facets if it has EAR facet checked.

Just for test you can try to export your project as EAR and then deploy it using web admin console.

Comment: When i "right click on Server > Add and Remove ..." i get "There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server". I just checked the Project Facet. They are correct set with Version 6.0

Comment: Expand your Ear project > Modules and see if you have web module there. If not you will have to add it via project Properties > Deployment Assembly. Then add and select your web project.

Comment: When i try to open Deployment Assembly for my Project i getting "The current displayed page contains invalid values." Do you have an example Project that i can see how it should be?

Comment: When i install the server new i see the Add and Remove form. And a message at the top say: "Cannot add an EAR project to the server unless it contains a Web, EJB, or Connector module." Look at my post i update the structure of my project in my ticket

Comment: Thx for your help. At the end i found a workaround which work for me.